# Android emulator loads infinitely

Tags: android, haxm

It seems, it takes place always with Intel x86 image. But my aim of this setting was using Inter HAXM.

I left emulator running on the whole night, but in the morning it still was booting

If I use arm, it works but I want to try HAXM

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just very slow, I recommend instead using Genymotion, but if you want to give a try fixing the speed take a look at this great topic: [Why is the Android emulator so slow? How can we speed up the Android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/why-is-the-android-emulator-so-slow)

I am pretty sure you will find your answer there.

Comment: Thank you for info about alternative emulator. I will try

Answer (score 0):

What are ur configurations? Using host gpu sometime makes it work

Answer (score 0):

Did you get the message

```
"HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode"
```

If not, are you sure you installed HAXM? If you just flag it in the SDK Manager, it's not automatically installed.

To verify if HAXM is installed and running use these commands:

Windows (CMD):

```
sc query intelhaxm
```

Mac (Terminal):

```
kextstat | grep intel
```

You either get a response like this (Mac):

```
131    0 0xffffff7f8301d000 0x14000    0x14000    com.intel.kext.intelhaxm (1) <7 5 4 3 1>
```

Or if it's not working, no response.

The installer haxm installer is located in your Android SDK folder

```
android-sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager
```

All the information can be found here:

Windows:
https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager

Mac:
https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-mac-os-x